# "access denied" error in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

We've decided to move one of our websites from one web hosting service to another. So, I backed up all the files and transfered them to the new host. Here's the problem I can't import the sql file into new database on the new host, I get "Access denied" error. weird. I'm using CPanel version 11.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the file permissions?

Comment: it's not file permission, I can upload the sql file, but I can not import it to the database.

Comment: is the db running as a different user than you used to upload the file -- it could still be the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of web hosts do not allow importing files with phpMyAdmin. However, you could easily get the same results with a quick PHP app.

Answer (score 0):

Try the http://www.adminer.org/ file. Just upload it and use it to import the file. If adminer shows an error then call your web hosting company as it might be a problem at their end.